# npm cannot fetch github subfolder

Tags: github, npm, fetch, subdirectory, package.json

I have a checked in github fork, and trying to be consumed via npm in another project.

Use rc-collapse, as example

URL: https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-collapse

github: https://github.com/react-component/collapse

```
npm install rc-collapse
cd node_modules
cd rc-collapse
dir

02/17/2017  11:21 PM    <DIR>          .
02/17/2017  11:21 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/17/2017  11:21 PM    <DIR>          assets
02/17/2017  11:21 PM               703 HISTORY.md
02/17/2017  11:21 PM    <DIR>          lib
02/17/2017  11:21 PM             1,083 LICENSE.md
02/17/2017  11:21 PM             3,140 package.json
02/17/2017  11:21 PM             4,073 README.md
```

However, after clear the folder, and use the following npm

```
npm install https://github.com/react-component/collapse
cd node_modules
cd rc-collapse
dir

02/17/2017  11:29 PM    <DIR>          .
02/17/2017  11:29 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/17/2017  11:29 PM               747 HISTORY.md
02/17/2017  11:29 PM             1,092 LICENSE.md
02/17/2017  11:29 PM             8,313 package.json
02/17/2017  11:29 PM             4,244 README.md
```

and again, after clear the folder, and use the following git command,

```
cd node_modules
git clone https://github.com/react-component/collapse rc-collapse
cd rc-collapse
dir

02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          .
02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/17/2017  11:38 PM               216 .gitignore
02/17/2017  11:38 PM               625 .travis.yml
02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          assets
02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          examples
02/17/2017  11:38 PM               747 HISTORY.md
02/17/2017  11:38 PM                37 index.js
02/17/2017  11:38 PM             1,092 LICENSE.md
02/17/2017  11:38 PM             1,482 package.json
02/17/2017  11:38 PM             4,244 README.md
02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          src
02/17/2017  11:38 PM    <DIR>          tests
```

Question/problem, I cannot get/use the fork from github, neither the lib folder  nor src folder is fetched using the npm command.

git clone is not the solution, because npm is used in the package.json fetching mechanism.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "rc-collapse": "git+https://github.com/react-component/collapse.git",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  }
```

The folders structure produced by the 'npm update' command is exactly same as the 'npm install https://github.com/react-component/collapse' command which is not usable, no source code included.

How npm fetch all subfolders by github url?

Comment: shouldn't the URL be the URL to your fork of the repository? 

e.g. `npm i --save https://github.com/YOUR_USERNAME/collapse.git`

Comment: any different fetching from my repository, or anyone repository? I have tried my repository too, no subfolder fetched.

Comment: could you give me a link to your repo? then I'll know better what you're talking about

Comment: try this >>    npm install https://github.com/wongchichong/collapse --save

Comment: try this >>    npm install https ://github.com/wongchichong/collapse --save    
with https no space....

Answer (score 1):

The author of the original package has set certain files in `package.json`. This means that it's not pulled when you run `npm install`. See this: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Files-and-Ignores.

Solution: Remove the following from `package.json`. Alternatively, you can add the folders you need.

```
 "files": [     
   "lib",       
   "assets/*.css"       
 ],
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the answer. Previous thought that npm github will do exactly the same as npm registry, but not the case. Now I have to modify package.json for every github project in order to use it properly.

Comment: @Eric np. I just learned that while trying to solve it, but it's good to know for future reference. btw, if you accept the answer, it'll mark your question as closed, helpful for others in the future